# VBA: filter multiple columns, then copy+paste

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I have tried unsuccessfully to filter multiple columns (of sheet data) and then copying a filtered column to another sheet (sheet2).
Initial situation:
The headers are in row 4:4

1. Filter column A by the string "SENR"
2. Copy the unique entries of column B into another sheet.

What have I achieved so far?
I was able to implement point 2) with the following code:

```
Sub CreateUniqueList()
Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("data").Select

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("B5:B" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1"), _
    Unique:=True

End Sub
```

However, I don't manage filter column A first according to point 1).
Does anyone here have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CreateUniqueList()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    Sheets("data").Select

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="SENR"

    Range("B5:B" & LastRow).Copy (Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"))

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, before posting I tried
```
Worksheets("data").Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="SENR"
```
Due to a typo it didn't work. Your solution does :) thanks alot

Comment: True, I only added the line with the criteria of "SENR" to my code above.

Comment: Please note that good answers in the VBA tag space generally [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) where possible.

Comment: @BigBen is correct, as usual.  I kept the Select in here to focus only on the part Alexsom23814 was missing, but for future reference that is absolutely the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know you want to filter by "SENR." You would need to add that value to a Criteria range and then call that out in your code.

Comment: I added the following line
```
Worksheets("data").Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="SENR"
```
However, it sets the filter range in row 1:1 instead of 4:4 where the headers are.

Comment: well NVM, i got a typo and that's why it didn't work